# Can't install the drivers for my nvidia geforce gpu on Debian 12

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, nvidia, gpu

I'm having trouble installing the drivers for my new rtx 4060ti gpu. Can anyone help me please? Thanks.

```
Setting up nvidia-kernel-dkms (525.147.05-4~deb12u1) ...
Loading new nvidia-current-525.147.05 DKMS files...
Building for 6.1.0-18-amd64
Building initial module for 6.1.0-18-amd64
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.1.0-18-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/525.147.05/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-kernel-dkms (--configure):
 installed nvidia-kernel-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver:
 nvidia-driver depends on nvidia-kernel-dkms (= 525.147.05-4~deb12u1) | nvidia-kernel-525.147.05 | nvidia-open-kernel-525.147.05 | nvidia-open-kernel-525.147.05; however:
  Package nvidia-kernel-dkms is not configured yet.
  Package nvidia-kernel-525.147.05 is not installed.
  Package nvidia-kernel-dkms which provides nvidia-kernel-525.147.05 is not configured yet.
  Package nvidia-open-kernel-525.147.05 is not installed.
  Package nvidia-open-kernel-525.147.05 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.36-9+deb12u4) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-18-amd64
Processing triggers for update-glx (1.2.2) ...
Processing triggers for glx-alternative-nvidia (1.2.2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia to provide /usr/lib/glx (glx) in auto mode
Processing triggers for glx-alternative-mesa (1.2.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.36-9+deb12u4) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-18-amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-kernel-dkms
 nvidia-driver
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```